# How to use babel polyfill with CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, babeljs

I'm writing a CouchDB application and using Babel polyfill. My design document contains two list functions. The `list_a` list use ES6 `Map` and the `list_b` use ES6 `Set`. They are defined like this:

`exports.list_a = function(header, req) {
        provides('json', function() {
        require('lib/babel-polyfill');
        ....
        }
}`

and

`exports.list_b = function(header, req) {
        provides('json', function() {
        require('lib/babel-polyfill');
        ....
        }
}`

- When I call list A first, one time or more, it works but then I got an error when calling list B that `Set` is not defined
- When I redeploy and call B first, one time ore more, it works but then I got an error when calling list A that `Map` is not defined

Does the multiple `require` are problematic? In the [babel documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) it says it should be required at the entry point of the application.

To my knowledge there is no "entry point" in a Couch app. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Is it possible at all to use ES6 in CouchDB design documents? I'm wondering if anybody got it working.

Comment: Simple things like using `let` and transpiling with babel works. Other more complex things like `for(x of obj)` do not work